# Lucene.Net - IndexWriter.SetMergedSegmentWarmer

Tags: c#, lucene.net

Anyone have an example of how to use [IndexWriter.SetMergedSegmentWarmer](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.9.4/html/c1d8e448-96a8-3e7c-2c82-929808df161f.htm) in Lucene.Net?

When I try something like...

```
IndexWriter.IndexReaderWarmer warmer = new IndexWriter.IndexReaderWarmer();
indexWriter.SetMergedSegmentWarmer(warmer);
```

I get

> Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.IndexReaderWarmer'

Comment: that means u need to find a concrete class that implements the contract provided by that.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a concrete class that inherits from `IndexReaderWarmer` in the Lucene code base?

Comment: I'm asking how to create a new instance of [IndexReaderWarmer](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.9.4/html/00063d1d-a888-51a1-6b87-f1c2302d780c.htm) so I can pass it to `IndexWriter.SetMergedSegmentWarmer`.

Comment: Not sure why it was down voted. Did my bit to correct that. This is an old pair of question & answer but valid in 2018 as far as core Lucene is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should write your own. `IndexWriter.IndexReaderWarmer` is abstract class, so it doesn't provide warm up implementation. The purpose of this class is to define contract between `IndexReader` and `IndexReaderWarmer` so they can communicate appropriately.

Writing your own implementation is not easy task. You should decide how exactly you will warm the reader up. Several ideas:

- perform recently executed queries over new reader;
- perform static bunch of queries;
- perform `FieldCache` preload only.

Comment: Thanks Denis. I think I got it working by creating a class that inherits from `IndexReaderWarmer` and overrides the `Warm` method with my warm up code. I'd post it as an answer here but apparently my question isn't real.  :-)